# Why is it taking so long to import a CSV and how can I speed it up?

Tags: android, csv

I have a fairly large CSV file (~.5Mb, 16000 rows, 6 columns) that I am currently importing into an array as part of an Android application. I store the CSV in assets folder and reimport it every time I use it. The import takes 7 or 8 seconds right now (~.47 ms per row).

Here's the code I'm using to read in the CSV:

```
         @Override
         protected ArrayList<Car> doInBackground(Void... voids) {
            ArrayList<Car> toReturn = new ArrayList<Car>(); 

            try {

                BufferedReader CSVFile = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(CarChooser.this.getAssets().open(CSV_NAME)));
                String dataRow = CSVFile.readLine();
                Car car;
                while (dataRow != null){
                    // split on the comma only if that comma has zero, or an even number of quotes in ahead of it
                    String[] dataArray = dataRow.split(",(?=([^\"]*\"[^\"]*\")*[^\"]*$)");
                    if(dataArray.length != 6) throw new IllegalStateException("Row length should be 6. Row length = " + dataArray.length);

                    int year = Integer.parseInt(dataArray[0]);
                    String make = Utils.removeQuotes(dataArray[1]);
                    String model = Utils.removeQuotes(dataArray[2]);
                    float mpgCty = Float.parseFloat(dataArray[3]);
                    float mpgHwy = Float.parseFloat(dataArray[4]);
                    float mpgCmb = Float.parseFloat(dataArray[5]);

                    car = new Car(year, make, model, mpgCty, mpgHwy, mpgCmb);

                    toReturn.add(car);

                    dataRow = CSVFile.readLine(); 
                }
                CSVFile.close();
            } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return toReturn;
         }
```

Here are my questions:

1. Is the time it's taking about what I should be expecting?
2. If not, why is it taking so long?
3. What is the best way to speed this whole process up?

I have no experience with SQL databases but it sounds like something I should look into.

Comment: Without knowing what you are doing with the data, its is hard to give any recommendations.  What are you doing with the list?

Comment: The list is used to populate 3 dependent spinners in which you choose the year of the car, then the make, then the model.

Comment: I'm not sure about your question as is, but I be willing to be a SQLite DB would be faster.  I'd then issue three queries to populate your spinners and based upon that find your car.  I can give more details in an answer, but again I don't have solid numbers saying it be faster.